# Android MAP intent for maps set to browser, how do I reset?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, maps

I have an app launching navigation with code similar to this:

```
  Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.35892,-71.05781&daddr=40.756054,-73.986951");
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     startActivity(intent);
```

In the emulator when I first ran, it asked me to choose the app, MAPS or WEB, I chose web, and now the emulator ALWAYS goes to google maps via web, how do I reset this setting so it will ask me again so I can test everthing with the maps application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to change the default application setting in the Manage Applications under the OS.  You can use this http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=43135   as a guide.

Comment: Okay, but WHICH application? When I selected WEB in the prompt it has changed all apps that fire off http://maps calls... so its not the APP that was running at the time that needs reset, but something else.. which one would it be?

Comment: You state that the browser (web) is now the default map application.  So, go to Manage Application>All>Browser>Clear Defaults